# Nested Query count ID if they're related

Tags: mysql

I've got a project where I need to get the total number of directors and films.

It should be 6 directors and 12 films in total.

However, I have 8 directors and 12 films.

```
CREATE TABLE `director` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 );

INSERT INTO `director` VALUES 
(1,'Roman Polanski'),
(2,'George Lucas'),
(3,'Steven Spielberg'),
(4,'Sam Mendes'),
(5,'Sofia Coppola'),
(6,'Michael Bay'),
(7,'Justin Lin'),
(8,'Francis Coppola');


CREATE TABLE `film` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`director_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 );


INSERT INTO `film` VALUES 
(1,'Saw',7),
(2,'Jaw',3),
(3,'The Pianist',1),
(4,'1917',4),
(5,'Fast and Furious',7),
(6,'Star Wars',2),
(7,'ET',3),
(8,'James bond',4),
(9,'Lost in Translation',5),
(10,'Close Encounter of the Third Kind',3),
(11,'Blood',4),
(12,'Somewhere',5);
```

And this is the query I used:

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   director
        ) AS directors,
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   film
        ) AS films
FROM    dual
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to count the director id only if it's related to the film's id?

Comment: (At the risk of being 'obvious'), what should the desired result set look like?

Comment: @Strawberry The desired set will have a directors column and films column. The directors column should be 6 and the films column should be 12.

Comment: Don't tell us. Show us. And edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Just count the distinct director IDs in the `film` table:

```
select
  count(*) as films,
  count(distinct director_id) as directors
from film
```

There is no need to touch the `director` table at all. But as an exercise you could do the following:

```
select count(*) as directors
from director d
where exists (
  select *
  from film f
  where f.director_id = d.id
)
```

Which will count directors who have ever directed a film.

See demo on [db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x17MYzmptzD5FZBWL8hCX1/0)